# How to get notified when a presented view controller is dismissed with a gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

It is possible in some cases (iPhone X, iOS 13) to dismiss presented view controllers with a gesture, by pulling from the top.

In that case, I can't seem to find a way to notify the presenting view controller. Did I miss something?

The only I found would be to add a delegate method to the viewDidDisappear of the presented view controller.

Something like:

```swift
class Presenting: UIViewController, PresentedDelegate {
    func someAction() {
        let presented = Presented()
        presented.delegate = self
        present(presented, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func presentedDidDismiss(_ presented: Presented) {
        // Presented was dismissed
    }
}

protocol PresentedDelegate: AnyObject {
    func presentedDidDismiss(_ presented: Presented)
}

class Presented: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: PresentedDelegate?

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
         ...
         delegate?.presentedDidDismiss(self)
    }
}
```

It is also possible to manage this via notifications, using a vc subclass but it is still not satisfactory.

```swift
extension Notification.Name {
    static let viewControllerDidDisappear = Notification.Name("UIViewController.viewControllerDidDisappear")
}

open class NotifyingViewController: UIViewController {

    override open func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .viewControllerDidDisappear, object: self)
    }
}
```

There must be a better way to do this?

Comment: do you mean iOS 13 presentation?

Comment: **It is possible on some iphones to dismiss presented view controllers with a gesture** || It is the default way of dismissing VC's on devices running 13.0 and above.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the original issue

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From iOS 13 Apple has introduced a new way for the users to `dismiss` the presented view controller by pulling it down from the top. This event can be captured by implementing the `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` to the `UIViewController` you're presenting on, in this case, the `Presenting` controller. And then you can get notified about this event in the method `presentationControllerDidDismiss`. Here is the code example :-

```
class Presenting: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {

    func someAction() {
        let presented = Presented()
        presented.presentationController?.delegate = self
        present(presented, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
        // Only called when the sheet is dismissed by DRAGGING.
        // You'll need something extra if you call .dismiss() on the child.
        // (I found that overriding dismiss in the child and calling
        // presentationController.delegate?.presentationControllerDidDismiss
        // works well).
    }
}
```

Note:

1. This method only gets triggered for dismissing by swiping from the top and not for the programmatic `dismiss(animated:,completion:)` method.
2. You don't need any custom delegate or `Notification` observer for getting the event where the user dismisses the controller by swiping down, so you can remove them.

Comment: Awesome, that works. I would upvote but apparently I don't have enough reputation.
Too bad it is only avaible for iOS 13 but I guess there are no standard animated dismissal before that. Thanks!

Comment: why `presentationControllerDidDismiss` is public ?

Comment: You need >15 reputations to upvote in SO. You're right no way for users to dismiss before view controller by swiping before iOS13 so no point in giving it using it for <iOS13

Comment: @jawadAli Thanks, I didn't notice that. Works both ways.

Answer (score 5):

Adopt `UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate` and implement `presentationControllerDidAttemptToDismiss` (iOS 13+)

```
extension Presenting : UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {

    func presentationControllerDidAttemptToDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
       presentationController.presentingViewController.presentedDidDismiss(self)
    }
}
```

`UIPresentationController` has a property `presentingViewController`. The name is self-explanatory. You don't need the explicit delegate protocol.

The method is actually called to be able to show a dialog for example to save changes before dismissing the controller. You can also implement `presentationControllerDidDismiss()`

And do not post notifications to controllers which are related to each other. That's bad practice.

Comment: @jawadAli Yes, the method has been introduced in iOS 13. In iOS 12 and below `viewWillDisappear` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the right path to the solution! I accepted @Frankenstein solution because it clarifies the delegate + uses `presentationControllerDidDismiss` which is more appropriate in my case!