Detect when a UIViewController gets dismissed by swiping down before the dismissal animation ends
With reference to this answer, the "endAppearanceTransition()" is called on the completion of the dismissal animation, about a second after the view disappears. I need to perform a specific task right after the UIViewController gets dismissed.
override func endAppearanceTransition() {
    if isBeingDismissed {
        // Dismissal Logic
    }
    super.endAppearanceTransition()
}

I tried implementing the logic in viewWillDisappear method, but the "isBeingDismissed" property is set to true when the user starts pulling the view controller down. But the user might abandon the dismissal process, in which case the dismissal logic should not execute.
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isBeingDismissed {
        // Dismissal Logic
    }
}


Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62340169/6257435

@DonMag Thanks for your response. This suffers the same drawback as well. By the time the delegate function gets called, the user might have performed other actions due to the time delay. I also tried implementing the logic in viewDidDisappear function. But none of them seem to solve the problem.
